# Does std::map::erase(it++) maintain a valid iterator pointing to the next element in the map?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, stdmap

I'm using Xcode with C++ 11 for a std::map. Some elements in my map have a flag that says they need to be removed.

I want to iterate through the map, erasing the flagged elements in O(n) time. The call to erase does not return an iterator. I have seen some kind of erase(it++) implementation, but I have no evidence that such a call can work since the iterator will become invalid after the erase operation but before the increment operation.

My current code seems so inefficient.

```
for(auto it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end(); ++it)
{
    delete *it;
    myMap.erase(it);
    it = myMap.begin(); //how can I avoid iterating through the map again
}
```

Comment: use `unique_ptr<>` to manage object lifetime then use `erase/remove_if` with a lambda that checks your removal flag. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove for an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the online documentation:

"Iterators, pointers and references referring to elements removed by the function are invalidated. All other iterators, pointers and references keep their validity."

So maybe this:

```
for(auto it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end();)
{
    auto itPrev = it;
    ++it;

    if(shouldBeDeleted(*itPrev))
       myMap.erase(itPrev);
}
```

Edit: The `erase(it++)` idea you mention is actually ok, because the increment occurs (and returns a copy of the old, pre-increment value) before `erase()` is called. It's in effect the equivalent of:

```
template<typename IteratorT>
IteratorT PostIncrement(IteratorT& it)
{
   auto copy = it;
   ++it;
   return copy;
}

for(auto it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end();)
   myMap.erase(PostIncrement(it));
```

which amounts to the same thing as the other example. Incidentally, this is why you should *normally* use the prefix ++ with iterators; that copy operation is extra overhead, and you usually don't need it.

Comment: what online documentation are you referring to?

Comment: The one I looked at is here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/erase/. That page also says C++11 should have `erase` overloads that return `iterator`s, but maybe they were left out of the implementation you're using.

Comment: OK, I did not notice the C++11 tab that I could click there. That seems to make sense, and I will mark it as correct if there are no errors.

Comment: Edited my answer with additional info.

Comment: The version of `std::map::erase()` that takes an interator as input and returns an iterator to the next element as output is not new in C++11, it existed in earlier versions as well.

Comment: This can be made slightly more elegant by using `auto itPrev = it++;` instead.

Answer (score 4):

When `std::map::erase()` is passed an iterator, it returns an iterator to the next element that follows the element being erased.  This allows you to continue your iteration without starting over.

Try this:

```
auto it = myMap.begin();
while (it != myMap.end())
{
    if (it->flagged)
    {
        delete *it;
        it = myMap.erase(it);
    }
    else
        ++it;
}
```

Comment: That is not true for Xcode's implementation of C++ 11 standard.